# Google Maps Web Service API returns different place id

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made two calls(**https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Singapore&key=MYAPIKEY**) in both local and server. But the response looks different.

**Server**:

```
{u'terms': [{u'value': u'Singapore', u'offset': 0}], u'description': u'Singapore', u'reference': u'CjQhAAAAqQkHLg3DEkoYCh6lVEJiqKveU1CMNkbK_6qQIcEZFtxd_NxVYVIbb1m2-koDTuBtEhDkB8K6HUla_TOyBQQDKAR3GhQ6-NKJG7K_w2XgfUtKuqTEFCR70A', u'structured_formatting': {u'main_text_matched_substrings': [{u'length': 9, u'offset': 0}], u'main_text': u'Singapore'}, u'matched_substrings': [{u'length': 9, u'offset': 0}], u'place_id': u'ChIJdZOLiiMR2jERxPWrUs9peIg', u'id': u'40c4b38e02b2cbbc038a8f25974c482dd9ee466f', u'types': [u'country', u'political', u'geocode']}
```

**Local**:

```
{u'terms': [{u'value': u'Singapore', u'offset': 0}], u'description': u'Singapore', u'reference': u'CjQhAAAAW1UCg8Y9NAxV8rFkCcTutkBeufvz4rT2DiqCHwMgefWa_xKk5bwy6XZeegDpgfCSEhAzfOhzl7AfxFQvKnPKZ9FaGhSA7Obi7wXY-NGXB6g6lZO66GrQ-w', u'structured_formatting': {u'main_text_matched_substrings': [{u'length': 9, u'offset': 0}], u'main_text': u'Singapore'}, u'matched_substrings': [{u'length': 9, u'offset': 0}], u'place_id': u'ChIJyY4rtGcX2jERIKTarqz3AAQ', u'id': u'de9886df6eae88551e41600d0927dc8eb9f2c6ca', u'types': [u'locality', u'political', u'geocode']}
```

From the above result, the **id** lookes different. Any reason?? 
And solution to get same result in both server and local.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

I will try and help to understand what is happening and how you can solve this.

As you can see the response from server returns a country place ID, because types are `[u'country', u'political', u'geocode']`. The response from local machine returns a city place ID, types are `[u'locality', u'political', u'geocode']`.

I suppose that geographical location of your local machine and your server are different. The place autocomplete also takes into account the public IP address of the machine that sent a request in case if you don't specify a viewport explicitly and bias results according to geographical location of the IP address. For example, when somebody searches Singapore from the US he/she typically means the country, so the country search is more popular in the US and suggested result is country. In contrary, local people probably search more often city than country, so in Singapore the city result has a higher prominence.

To solve your issue and get the same result you should specify a viewport applying the location and radius parameters in your request.

Let's set a center of view  port to 1.395126,103.831787 and radius to 50km

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Singapore&location=1.395126%2C103.831787&radius=50000&key=YOUR_API_KEY

you will see that result is locality as shown in my screenshot[image]

Now increase the radius to 500km

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Singapore&location=1.395126%2C103.831787&radius=500000&key=YOUR_API_KEY

you will see that for this bigger area the preferred result is now country[image]

I hope this explains your doubt.